# Creating custom file formats according to specifications

Tags: labview, file-format

I have a program which produces data which needs to be stored in the specific [.fsc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_Cytometry_Standard) format. This format is used in flow cytometry experiments ("counting cells in liquid"). The file is basically a ASCII header and binary experiment data. A detailed description of the file standard can be found [here](http://isac-net.org/Resources/Standards/FCS3-1.aspx).

I am new "exotic" file creation, so what I need to know is **how do I create such a file?**, according to the specifications.

I am getting confused by the combination of ASCII characters for the header and binary values for the data. How do I combine these two. I will be using LabVIEW for this, where I can create files containing only text, and binary files where everything has binary values, but not both. Or is it as simple as creating a *.txt* file in which I write the ASCII header and the converted binary values of my data, and then simly changing the file extension from *.txt* to *.fsc*?

Answer (score 5):

In principal every file is a binary file, whether we can read it as text file is dependent on whether the bytes are formatted in an ASCII format where specific rules apply to binary numbers representing an ASCII value. The translation from binary to ASCII character is easy to see in any [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

In the case of an FSC format it stipulates that the header should be saved in the ASCII standard (so flat text). The actual data can be stored in a number of formats depending on what you specify in the header.

From the [FSC Standard 3.3 Data Segment section](http://isac-net.org/Resources/Standards/FCS3-1.aspx) this is the excerpt for the data format:

> The DATA segment contains the raw data in one of three modes (list, correlated or uncorrelated)
>   described in the primary TEXT segment by the $MODE keyword value. The data are written to
>   the DATA segment in one of four allowed formats (binary, floating point, double precision floating
>   point or ASCII) described by the $DATATYPE keyword value (see also the description of the
>   $DATATYPE keyword).

So the data can be anything, including ASCII.

For reading the data you will need to read the header as ASCII format, interpret the header info and read the rest of the file in the specified format from the first byte after the header.

A possible shortcut is if your instrument (or any flow cyclometer) has a labview driver and see if they have a library available for the reading of FCS files

Answer (score 2):

To add a few points to D.J.Klomp's good answer:

- LabVIEW is not Unicode-aware by default, so it treats strings as sequences of characters which are always 8-bit bytes. This means you can use the string datatype to handle any byte sequence data whether or not it is actually "text".
- As far as I can see from a quick scan of the specification, you should be able to create all the text-format data by careful use of LabVIEW's **Format into String** function. Note that this appends its output to whatever string you wire to the `initial string` input, so you can chain them together to build up your data in multiple operations.
- If you need to use binary-format data (and from the quote in your question it looks as if you may not need to, unless the destination for this data doesn't support the other allowed types?) you can prepare it in an array of `U8` integers then convert it to a string using **Byte Array to String**.
- The spec mentions a CRC value for each segment but suggests its use is optional - if the program or instrument you're sending this file to complains about a missing CRC you should be able to find a VI to calculate it on the NI website. I can't remember which one(s) I've used in the past but from a quick search the one in the [answer here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/CRC-16-CCITT-of-serial-packets/td-p/1471386) sounds like it ought to work.